# Ubuntu distribution for a broadcom bcm4313 wireless driver and an nvidia 630 graphics adapter

Tags: broadcom, nvidia-optimus, distro-recommendation

I've struggled with driver issues in the last few Ubuntu versions

I am currently using an HP DV6 laptop that has a Broadcom BCM4313 wireless driver and the nvidia 630GTM graphics (optimus) driver.  I would really appreciate if you guys could suggest a distro that has full support for these devices.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the latest Ubuntu distribution (12.10) provides excellent support for numerous graphic drivers, and the b43 driver for BCM4313.

You can install the `b43` driver using APT:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

and restart your PC.

Comment: Thanks @Geckobear for your quick response, but have you used ubuntu 12.10 and do you think its better than the LTS version? I mean in terms of support for the drivers. I just want to be a 100% sure that its the best solution for my laptop.

Comment: I'm currently writting this from a 12.10 laptop with the b43 driver. It works flawlessly. Though I don't know about the NVidia drivers 'cause I'm using the Radeon Open driver -- which also runs flawlessly!--. 12.10 is sure a bigger step forward from 12.04. You can always try for yourself and make the final descision. Also, if the driver works, you could contribute at http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43 as it is marked as "Not tested".

Comment: Can anybody tell me how to get a broacom 4313 chip to work in 12.04 or 12.10? Which drivers to install? I am really confused!

Comment: uhm..with the above command it will most likely work out of the box... did you try it?

Comment: I've been using Ubuntu 12.10 on my HP Envy 6 (with BCM4313 14e4:4727). The wireless is significantly improved. Ping times are stable (< 1ms to my router). I'd say give it a shot.

Note: I did not need to use the `firmware-b43-installer` suggested in the post above. The card worked out of the box with no issues.

Comment: @bkloppenborg thanks a lot for replying! I had been waiting for somebody who actually got the wifi working with the bcm 4313 chipset. I am using an hp dv6 7011tx which also has a broadcom bcm 43113 GN 802.11n wireless adapter. I tried setting up the wifi in 11.10 by installing the proprietary STA adapters in the additional drivers section but in vain. I wanted to try the LTS 12.04 with a live USB but the wifi could not work out of the box. Did you install some additional drivers? Nothing? I will definitely give this a shot and let you know how it goes! Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Geckobear but the firmware-b43-installer does not support the bcm 4313 chip, I checked the info in the software center.

Comment: @VivekPradhan By using a PPA I was also able to get the [BCM4313 to work on 12.04](http://bkloppenborg.github.com/blog/2012/09/02/installing-ubuntu-12-04-on-the-hp-envy-6/) (about half-way down on that page), although the stability left much to be desired (wireless would drop once for every few hours of use and ping times to a local router were > 2-5 ms on average).

Comment: The additional STA proprietary driver seems to be working ok till now, without major hitches. I just ensure that the wireless is not hardblocked, because it causes problems some times. Thanks for your help.